# Loop objects in a json array by using Json.net [C#]

Tags: c#, json, json.net

## Description:

I have a string **str** like below:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value3",
    "key2": "value4"
  }
]
```

I know I could deserialize it to json like

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomType>(str).
```

Now I have a requirement to loop these objects and get the values. How should I do?

Comment: Your json string is a list. You cannot deserialize it like that. What does your `CustomType` class look like?

Comment: Just use foreach(var item in CustomTypeList){  //here get item }

Comment: Actually, I don't want to create a new class to map the json keys. I just want to loop the array to get the key and value in each object.

Comment: It seems like you want a dictionary, but your json should be different for that. Dictionary json would look like this: `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`Then you would deserialize it like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>(str);` Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JArray array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

foreach(JObject item in array)
{
    var a = item.Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault().Name;
    var b = item.Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault().Value;

}
```

Here if you have only one property in every element of the array. If you have multiple properties you need to loop all the children.

Check [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/frjXsS) for full code example.

**EDIT**

If you have more than one property per object your loop should look like this.

```
        foreach(JObject item in array)
        {
            foreach(var prop in item.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(item.Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault().Name + ": " + item.Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault().Value);

        }
```

Comment: it should have more properties, what's the type of item.children<JProperty>()? JEnumerable<Jproperty>? Sorry I am new to C#. update question.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize your json string to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(str);
```

Then loop this list

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach(Dictionary<string, string> dict in list)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvPair in dict)
    {
        values.Add(kvPair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you time to answer, the two solution both looks good.